# Bind function call in object

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, slickgrid, deferred

**Goal**: Execute function when function -defined in object- is called

Example:

```
var obj = {
    endUpdate: function(){
       ... (async stuff from library, cannot modify this code)
    }
}
```

I want to write something like this, to know when *endUpdate* has been called

```
obj.on('endUpdate', function(){
    // do stuff here when "endUpdate" in above object is called
})
```

Comment: You can raise a custom event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Comment: I get error "Uncaught TypeError: g.addEventListener is not a function", screenshot here: https://i.imgur.com/2UeO6ug.png

Comment: This is tagged 'SlickGrid', hence my interest. Perhaps you should give us a little more info around how SlickGrid or the event is being set up and called.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a subscriber function quite easily like so

```
var obj = {
   listeners: {
      endUpdate: []
   },
   on: function(name, callbackFn){
      this.listeners[name].push(callbackFn);
   },
   runListeners: function(name) {
      this.listeners[name].forEach((fn) => fn());
   },
   endUpdate: async function(){
       await someStuffFromLib();
       this.runListeners('endUpdate');
   }
}
```

Otherwise you can enhance the object and chain async functions as long as you maintain the chain all the way through

```
 var obj = {
   endUpdate: function(){
      const thisIsAPromise = someStuffFromLib();
      return thisIsAPromise;
   }
}

const newObj = {
    endUpdate: (...args) => obj.endUpdate(...args).then(
                (result) => { console.log(result)})
}
```

Comment: I cannot modify the original variable "obj"

Comment: *I cannot modify the original variable "obj"* this is pretty important - you should have mentioned this in the question.

Comment: I did, see my comment "async stuff from library, cannot modify this code". Thank you for your effort / time and help in any case, appreciate it alot